# How to calculate the difference of two values including their standard deviation in R?

Tags: r, statistics, difference

I have following values:

```
x <- c(20.00740, 38.108416, 56.832884)  #x0 of peaks
sx <- c(0.1435, 0.011667, 0.027201)  # std. error of x0
```

I want to calculate the difference between each peak with error propagation. I should receive two difference values with std. error. How can I do this in R?

Cheers,
Kris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For random variables X and Y use the fact that E(X-Y) = EX - EY, sd(X) = sqrt(var(X)) and var(X-Y) = var(X) + var(Y).  The last equation assumes X and Y are uncorrelated.

Now, if we label the peaks A, B, C then there exist the differences A-B, A-C and B-C which is 3 difference values, not 2 (6 differences if A-B and B-A etc. are distinguised).   They are computed in the upper (or lower) triangle of the `xx` and `ss` matrices below.  `xx[upper.tri(xx)]` and `ss[upper.tri(xx)]` would extract the upper triangular values.

```
xx <- outer(x, x, "-"); xx
##          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
## [1,]  0.00000 -18.10102 -36.82548
## [2,] 18.10102   0.00000 -18.72447
## [3,] 36.82548  18.72447   0.00000

ss <- sqrt(outer(sx^2, sx^2, "+")) * !diag(length(sx)); ss
##           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
## [1,] 0.0000000 0.14397350 0.14605528
## [2,] 0.1439735 0.00000000 0.02959752
## [3,] 0.1460553 0.02959752 0.00000000
```